# Manual testing a stateless function in oracle sql in SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've coded the most complex sql function ever:

```
function abc() RETURN 7;
```

I'd like to verify my function actually does what I think it does : to return a 7.

What's the easiest way to accomplish that with sql-developer?

Answer (score 1):

`function abc() RETURN 7;` This is not a valid declaration of a function.

Let's try something like this:

```
SQL> create or replace function abc
  2  return number
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    return 7;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created
```

To see result of the function just query `dual` table with the function name being listed in the select part of a query. Using this method be sure that the function does not contain any DML statements.

```
SQL> 
SQL> select abc
  2    from dual
  3  /

       ABC
----------
         7
```